# Can one read input into a element of a associative array?

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to use `read` to put data into a particular element of an associative array, so I wrote the following:

```
typeset -Ag aa
aa[key]='initial value'
...
read aa[key]
```

which produces an error: `no matches found: aa[key]`

So I write the following instead and it works:

```
typeset -Ag aa
aa[key]='initial value'
...
local line
read line
aa[key]=line
```

Is there a way to skip the temporary variable `line`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that zsh trys to do globbing somehow for the `aa[key]` token.

So, it would be fine to turn off globbing temporally using `noglob` or quoting that token.

```sh
echo val0 | noglob read aa[key]; echo $aa[key] ;# => val0

echo val1 | read 'aa[key]'; echo $aa[key] ;# => val1
```

---

> noglob
>
> Filename generation (globbing) is not performed on any of the words.
>
> -- [`zshmisc(1)` Precommand modifires](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Precommand-Modifiers)

Comment: Quoting the key is perfect for my needs, and actually kind of obvious. I really should have thought to try that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed: `aa[key]` is a pattern that matches `aak`, `aae`, or `aay`.